# hstack throws ValueError: wrong dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I try to concat two matrices along the columns (as [a,b] in matlab). But I'm keep getting the error:

`ValueError: arrays must have same number of dimensions`

This my code:

```
print a.shape
print b.shape 
X= np.hstack([b,a])
```

And this is the output:

```
(223129, 1)
(223129, 4)
```

It my understanding, the dimensions are fine. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found my error. One of my matrix was a **sparse matrix**, and then you get the error I had.

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `b` have different number of dimensions. Do `a.ndim` or `b.ndim`. The results should be equal.

If `a` and `b` have the dimensions that you seem to indicate, then it should work.

e.g.

```
a=np.ones((5,1))
b=np.ones((5,4))
np.hstack([b,a])
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

It works for me if I use the same shapes {(223129,1) and (223129,4)}  for `a` and `b` that you indicate.